# Given the following derivatives, find the integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Find the derivatives of $\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$ and $\arcsin(x)$, and use the result to find the integrals of the following functions:
>
> - $$ \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{ \pm x^2 \pm a^2 }} $$
> - $$ \sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2} $$
>
> Except for the cases where both are minuses. $a$ is a positive constant.

So for the two derivatives, I just found the following derivatives $$[\ln (x+\sqrt{x^2 \pm a^2}) ]' = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 \pm a^2}}$$

And also:

$$ [ b\arcsin(\dfrac{x}{a} + c)]' = \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2-(x+ac)^2}}$$

These formules make the first part easy. We get $\int \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{ x^2 + a^2 }} = \ln (x+\sqrt{x^2 + a^2})$, $\int \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{ x^2 - a^2 }} = \ln (x+\sqrt{x^2 - a^2})$ and $\int \dfrac{1}{ \sqrt{ a^2 - x^2 }} = \arcsin(\dfrac{x}{a})$

However, I am not able to figure out what the easiest way is to get the second part of the question, using the knowledge we have. Can someone help out.

Comment: As an aside, $\ln\Big(x+\sqrt{x^2+1}\Big)$ is also known among friends as $\text{arcsinh }x$. And just like $\arcsin'x$ $=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, in the same manner, $\text{arcsinh}'x=\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** You may use an integration by parts for the second family:
$$
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2} \:{\rm{d}}x&=x\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}-\int \frac{x \times\pm x }{\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}}\:{\rm{d}}x\\
&=x\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}-\int \frac{\pm x^2}{\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}}\:{\rm{d}}x\\
&=x\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}-\int \frac{\pm x^2 \pm a^2 -\pm a^2}{\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}}\:{\rm{d}}x\\
&=x\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}-\int \sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2} \:{\rm{d}}x+\pm a^2\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}}\:{\rm{d}}x
\end{align}
$$ giving
$$
\int \sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2} \:{\rm{d}}x=\frac x2\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}+\frac{\pm a^2}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pm x^2 \pm a^2}}\:{\rm{d}}x
$$
then you conclude with the first family.